# Can a moderator mark an answer as correct?

Tags: support, accepted-answer

In [this](https://superuser.com/questions/671753/difference-between-search-and-nameserver-in-resolv-conf) question, the asker has said [in a comment](https://superuser.com/questions/671753/difference-between-search-and-nameserver-in-resolv-conf#comment850022_671756) that one of the answers is correct.

However, he has not marked the answer. Is it possible for someone else to?

Comment: Short answer: No.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg Long answer?

Comment: Still "no". Asker is the only one that has such privileges.

Comment: Okay. He specified short answer so I guessed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

It has been [suggested that we allow others to mark accepted an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26639/allow-users-to-mark-accepted-answer-on-someone-elses-question) on the questioner's behalf, but not likely to happen.

The accepted answer is the one chosen by the person asking as they feel it best solves their problem.